# HTTP Very Low Level Requests By PHP

Tags: php, http, api

I was thinking how can I write a function in PHP which will take a single string argument as follows:

```
function executeHTTP($cmd)
{
   //some way to execute $cmd
}
```

Now $cmd is what it contains...

```
$cmd = "
POST /action/GetUploadToken HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: AuthSub token="DXAA...sdb8"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=adf15ee97731bca89da876c...a8dc
Content-Length: 1941255
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">
      I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.
    </media:description>
    <media:category
      scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People
    </media:category>
    <media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
</entry>
"
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: It looks this is the right answer. I will try prior to mark it answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the cURL extension: https://www.php.net/curl

Answer (score 1):

Using fsockopen, as zoldar said, you can make a raw HTTP request.

```
function executeHTTP($cmd,$host="gdata.youtube.com",$port=80)
{
    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
        return false;
    } else {
        fwrite($fp, $cmd);
        $data = fread($fp);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

you'll need to also specify the host and port, but you can set defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [YouTube's PHP SDK](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html)?